# Favicon: ¿formato ico o png?¿y qué rel?

Tags: html, html5

Normalmente incluía un favicon en mis páginas web con un icono `.ico`, haciendo algo como esto:

```
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" />
```

Pero he visto que bastante sitios web lo hacen con imágenes con extensión `.png`, y con diferentes valores para el atributo `rel` (como "shortcut icon" o "apple-touch-icon").

¿Qué formato de imagen es más apropiado para favicon en los navegadores modernos? ¿Cuáles son las ventajas de usar uno sobre el otro? Y lo mismo para el atributo `rel`: ¿hay alguna diferencia entre "icon" o "shortcut icon"? (asumiendo que "apple-touch-icon" es específico para dispositivos Apple)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Casi todos los navegadores ya cuentan con un soporte extenso de diferentes formatos de imágenes para mostrar el [favicon](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) de una página siendo Internet Explorer y Safari (los sospechosos de siempre) los que cuentan con menor soporte. Aquí la lista.

**Edge**: `.ico`, `.png`, `.gif`

**Firefox**: `.ico`, `.png`, `.gif`, `.gif` animado, `.jpg`, `.png` animado, `.svg`

**Chrome**: `.ico`, `.png`, `.gif`, `.gif` animado, `.jpg`

**IE**: `.ico`, `.png`, `.gif`

**Opera**: `.ico`, `.png`, `.gif`, `.gif` animado, `.jpg`, `.png` animado, `.svg`

**Safari**: `.ico`, `.png`, `.gif`, `.jpg`

Como verás casi siempre el factor común es `ico`, `png` y `gif`. Resulta que este último no es precisamente muy bueno haciendo transparencias ni imágenes de calidad como puedes leer en la misma [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF) lo cual nos deja con sólo dos tipos ideales para este propósito; `ico` y `png`.

Los íconos pueden tener tamaños de 16×16, 32×32, 48×48, o 64×64 píxeles y 8 bits, 24 bits o 32 bits de profundidad de color. Personalmente he usado `png` de dimensiones enormes y no proporcionales (a manera de experimento) y el navegador los ha renderizado sin problemas lo que convierte este formato en el ideal (en mi opinión).

Puedes usar ambos formatos a la vez y también los navegadores intentarán obtenerlo de la raíz del sitio por defecto. Este proceso se hace siguiendo este algoritmo.

Si vínculos para ambos favicons en formato PNG y ICO son encontrados los navegadores compatibles con PNG seleccionan que formato y tamaño usar de la siguiente manera:

- Firefox y Safari usarán el favicon que venga de último.
- Chrome para Mac usará cualquiera que sea en formato ICO, de lo contrario usará el que tenga 32×32 píxeles.
- Chrome para Windows usará el favicon que venga primero si es 16×16 píxeles de tamaño, de lo contrario el ICO.
- Si ninguna de las opciones anteriores son posibles, ambos Chromes usarán cualquier favicon venga primero, exactamente el opuesto de Firefox y Safari. De hecho, Chrome para Mac ignorará el de 16×16 y usará el de 32×32 para luego escalarlo a 16x16 en dispositivos no-retina.
- Opera escogerá el icono completamente al azar.

Recuerda que el atributo `rel` esta relacionado con el elemento [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/link) que puede usarse para muchas cosas más como cargar estilos y su sintáxis es:

```
<link rel="[tipo enlace][espacio][tipo enlace]..."/>
```

Los [tipos de enlaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Tipos_de_enlaces) a los que te refieres son `icon` y `shorcut`.

- `icon`: Define un recurso para representar la página en la interfaz de usuario, usualmente un icono (audible or visual).

  Básicamente es una imagen que identifica tu página.
- `shorcut`: No forma parte del estándar.

  Se usa por razones históricas.

> Por razones históricas, la palabra clave icon puede ir precedida por la palabra clave "shortcut". Si "shortcut" está presente debe venir seguida inmediatamente por icon y ambas deben ir separadas por un sólo caracter U+0020 SPACE.

Básicamente con `icon` es suficiente a menos que pretendas soportar navegadores antiguos en tu sitio.

Answer (score 5):

Yo seguiría usando  `.ico` ya que es el formato mas soportado en todos los navegadores.
Ahora, según recuerdo eso lo vi en una de mis clases en la Universidad, que el atributo **rel="shortcut icon"** de un **favicon** fue definido por Internet Explorer y era para hacer mención de la relación entre *ícono y página*, no fue hasta la aparición de HTML5(No se realmente que año fue xD) fue cuando declaró que `icon` sería el identificador estandarizado, eso si, según yo solo en navegadores que no sean basados en **IE** pueden usar el favicon sin la necesidad del `shortcut` .

Chrome, Firefox, Opera y Safari aceptan favicons **PNG** ...**Peeeeroooo** Chrome y Safari siempre optarán por el `.ico` si es que existen ambos

```
 <!-- Chrome, Safari, IE -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="path/to/favicon.ico">

<!-- Firefox, Opera  -->
<link rel="icon" href="path/to/favicon.png">
```

Desde que apareció el uso de PNG, no se incluyen múltiples resoluciones, habría que escribirlos manualmente :.

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon-16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon-32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon-48.png" sizes="48x48">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon-64.png" sizes="64x64">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon-128.png" sizes="128x128">
```

Por lo tanto, no sería pregunta *¿Cuál es el formato mas apropiado?* ya que siempre será la prioridad el `.ico` xD

En cuanto a los “Touch icons” son favicons para dispositivos móviles y tablets, iOS añade automáticamente algunos efectos visuales, esto para coordinar con los íconos incorporados a la pantalla de inicio (como lo hace con los íconos de aplicaciones). En concreto, el IOS añade:

**Esquinas redondeadas**

**gota de sombra**

**brillo reflectante**

A partir de iOS 2.0, se puede evitar la adición de estos efectos mediante el uso de la **precompose**:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
```

En realidad tiene muchas propiedades, aquí está muy bien explicado:

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons