# ¿Cómo agregar icono sobre el título de la página(pestaña)?

Tags: html, html5

Quisiera saber cómo lograr poner un icono sobre el título de la página(En la pestaña).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

html

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 "/>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1 ">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>  @ViewBag.Title</title>
<!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
</head>
```

He intentado poniendo una imagen sobre la etiqueta tittle antes de @ViewBag.Title, pero no me permite, me muestra que no se puede agregar sobre esa etiqueta.

Si pueden apoyarme se los agradecería mucho. Saludos.

Comment: Mas que un problema de html es un tema del serivdor, deberias fijarte con que servidor web estas trabajando y como se le configura un favico. Por lo de @viewbag intuyo que es un IIS, pero podria estar equivocado

Comment: Hola Sacha, gracias por tu comentario, si es un IIS

Comment: Si no me equivoco lo tenes que dejar en la raiz del sitio y el IIS lo tomara. Tiene que ser llamado favicon.ico

Comment: Esta pregunta que hice hace un tiempo puede serte de utilidad: [Favicon: ¿formato ico o png?¿y qué rel?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/22067/250)

Comment: dentro de las respuestas las que tienen link con atributo type="image/x-icon", esas son las respuestas completas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debe de ser con la siguiente etiqueta

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/es/img/favicon.ico?v=a8def514be8a">
```

La cual se inserta después de la etiqueta title o dentro de tu head de tu HTML. La extensión de la imagen debe de ser en .ico, hay muchos generadores de favicon online.

Por ejemplo:
https://www.favicon-generator.org/

---

### **Actualización**

Casi todos los navegadores ya cuentan con un soporte extenso de diferentes formatos de imágenes, y no solo .ico. Más info en [esta otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22082/12625).

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió  tu respuesta también la que ya había logrado. *<link type="image/x-icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/es/img/favicon.ico?v=a8def514be8a" rel="icon" />

Comment: @masha10 Si la respuesta te ayudo a tu objetivo, marcala como correcta para ayudar a más usuarios a encontrarla más fácil.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Actualice mi respuesta con la respuesta correcta de la otra pregunta. Gracias :)

Comment: Ya la marqué como correcta :D muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 3):

Hola esto va en la etiqueta `<head></head>`
así

```html
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
```

el href tiene que tener la dirección donde tienes guardado el icono.
ojo que tiene que estar en formato `.ico`
Te dejo el link para hacer iconos.
[Enlace para hacer iconos](http://www.genfavicon.com/es/)

Answer (score 3):

Es así, espero te sirva............

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Dirección del icono que vayas a poner" type="image/x-icon">
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo agrega la cabecera a tu html con la ruta de tu `favicon`, el tipo puede ser `image/x-icon`  de esta manera

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```